# How to get secure cookie in postman using interceptor

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

i am using postman to testing my api endpoints , which needs cookie values as input. so to get the cookies i have installed Interceptor and enabled both in chrome browser and also in postman.

Problem is i am getting only those cookies which are marked "Secure" false not finding any "cookie" which is marked "Secure" true in postman.

So, how to also get cookies marked secure in postman ?

sample code

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("CartKey",postman.getResponseCookie("CartKey").value);
```